# How can I get the index of array element inside object?

Tags: javascript, html, indexof

```
const questions = [
    {
      "question": "What is the scientific name of a butterfly?",
      "answers": ["Apis", "Coleoptera", "Formicidae", "Rhopalocera"],
      "correctIndex": 3
    },
    {
      "question": "How hot is the surface of the sun?",
      "answers": ["1,233 K", "5,778 K", "12,130 K", "101,300 K"],
      "correctIndex": 1
    },
]
```

I'm trying this way but return -1:

`console.log(questions.findIndex(value => value.answers.indexOf() === 'Apis'));`

For example if wanna get the indexOf 'Apis', i get -1.

I'm trying to compare 'CorrectIndex' value with index of answers array value and return if its correct or not.

Comment: `questions` is an array, which could possibly contain more than one item. What should be done if there's more than one? Do we know what index to use to get to the right question-answer item before getting the answer index?

Comment: `value.answers.indexOf()` is missing an argument. Why are you trying to compare a number to a string?

Comment: Your question lacks context. Where does `'Apis'` come from? How do you know to which question in `questions` it needs to be compared to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just used indexOf in a wrong way. That's quite simple to fix:

```js
const questions = [
    {
      question: "What is the scientific name of a butterfly?",
      answers: ["Apis", "Coleoptera", "Formicidae", "Rhopalocera"],
      correctIndex: 3
    },
    {
      question: "How hot is the surface of the sun?",
      answers: ["1,233 K", "5,778 K", "12,130 K", "101,300 K"],
      correctIndex: 1
    }
]

questions.forEach(question => {
  console.log(question.answers.indexOf('Apis'))
});
```

Realize that indexOf is a function and recives a string.

Comment: `value.answers.indexOf('Apis')>-1`

Comment: @SulmanMalik can you check out my snippet? I updated it and it's working now

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you want to get the index of element in `answers` array of this object.
try this:

```
console.log(questions.map(value => value.answers.indexOf('Apis')));
```

this will give you an array of indexes whose value is "Apis".

If you have duplicate values in same array, you can do this:

```
console.log(questions.map(value => [value.answers.indexOf('Apis')]));
```

This will store an array of the array in which you can get the indexes of "Apis" of each object.

> I'm trying to compare 'CorrectIndex' value with index of answers array
> value and return if its correct or not.

### Try this

```js
const questions = [
    {
      "question": "What is the scientific name of a butterfly?",
      "answers": ["Apis", "Coleoptera", "Formicidae", "Rhopalocera"],
      "correctIndex": 3
    },
    {
      "question": "How hot is the surface of the sun?",
      "answers": ["1,233 K", "5,778 K", "12,130 K", "101,300 K"],
      "correctIndex": 1
    },
]

console.log(questions.map(value => value.answers.indexOf('Apis') === value.correctIndex));
```

Comment: Thats because "Apis" is the first element of array.

Comment: Do you want the object's index in which answers' array has Apis in it?

Comment: And so if the correct answer to the 'question' "What is the scientific name of a butterfly?" is Rhopalocera due to the fact that your 'correctIndex' is set to 3.  And index of 3 means that this is the 4th element of the array.

Comment: Adding other values still returns 0

Comment: I have modified my answer a bit. Have a look and let me know if this is working.

Answer (score 0):

why are  u comparing `value.answers.indexOf()`

the correct syntax should be

```
console.log(questions.findIndex(value => value.answers.indexOf('element')));
```